# How to use font-awesome icons from node-modules

Tags: css, node.js, less, npm, font-awesome

I have installed font-awesome 4.0.3 icons using `npm install`.

If I need to use it from node-modules how should I use it in html file?

If I need to edit the less file do I need to edit it in node-modules?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the "correct" way to do this?  I'm currently just using a gulp task to copy the stuff out of node_modules into my public directory.

Comment: I used it as bower component later...

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Install as `npm install font-awesome --save-dev`

In your development less file, you can either import the whole font awesome less using `@import "node_modules/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less"`, or look in that file and import just the components that you need. I think this is the minimum for basic icons:

```
/* adjust path as needed */
@fa_path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/less";
@import "@{fa_path}/variables.less";
@import "@{fa_path}/mixins.less";
@import "@{fa_path}/path.less";
@import "@{fa_path}/core.less";
@import "@{fa_path}/icons.less";
```

*As a note, you still aren't going to save that many bytes by doing this. Either way, you're going to end up including between 2-3k lines of unminified CSS.*

You'll also need to serve the fonts themselves from a folder called`/fonts/` in your public directory. You could just copy them there with a simple gulp task, for example:

```
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/fonts'))
})
```

Comment: It needs to be stressed more that the fonts also needed to be served to a fonts folder...  I probably spent an hour trying to figure out this simple little thing.

Comment: You can also adapt the font statics path by setting the variable ``fa-font-path`` to your desired location.

Comment: In the above example, you need to follow your less imports with the following override so that the font-awesome font files copied by gulp will be found after deployment: `@fa-font-path: "/public/fonts";`

Answer (score 59):

You have to set the proper font path. e.g.

#### my-style.scss

```
$fa-font-path:"../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
.icon-user {
  @extend .fa;
  @extend .fa-user;
}
```

Comment: The same for sass. Path `../assets/font-awesome/fonts` works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Add the below to your `.css` stylesheet.

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import url('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

Answer (score 14):

You will need to copy the files as part of your build process. For example, you can use a `npm postinstall` script to copy the files to the correct directory:

```json
"postinstall": "cp -R node_modules/font-awesome/fonts ./public/"
```

For some build tools, there are preexisting font-awesome packages. For example, webpack has [font-awesome-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome-webpack) which lets you simple `require('font-awesome-webpack')`.

Answer (score 13):

Using webpack and scss:

Install font-awesome using npm (using the setup instructions on https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use)

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Next, using the **copy-webpack-plugin**, copy the **webfonts** folder from **node_modules** to your **dist** folder during your webpack build process. (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin)

```
npm install copy-webpack-plugin
```

In **webpack.config.js**, configure **copy-webpack-plugin**. NOTE: The default webpack 4 dist folder is "dist", so we are copying the webfonts folder from node_modules to the dist folder.

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts', to: './webfonts'}
        ])
    ]
}
```

Lastly, in your **main.scss** file, tell fontawesome where the **webfonts** folder has been copied to and import the SCSS files you want from **node_modules**.

```
$fa-font-path: "/webfonts"; // destination folder in dist
//Adapt the path to be relative to your main.scss file
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";

//Include at least one of the below, depending on what icons you want.
//Adapt the path to be relative to your main.scss file
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";

@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims"; // if you also want to use `fa v4`  like: `fa fa-address-book-o`
```

and apply the following `font-family` to a desired region(s) in your html document where you want to use the fontawesome icons.

**Example**:

```
 body {
      font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'; // if you use fa v5 (regular/solid)
      // font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands'; // if you use fa v5 (brands)
    }
```

Comment: works fine for me, I just had to adjust the path from `@import "../node_modules/[...]"` to `@import "@/../node_modules/[...]"`

Comment: You can add an alias to webpack.config.js: `resolve: {alias: {'node_modules': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')}}` and then `@import "node_modules/[...]`

Comment: Too many steps for some icons. Incredible. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 9):

With expressjs, public it:

```
app.use('/stylesheets/fontawesome', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/'));
```

And you can see it at: `yourdomain.com/stylesheets/fontawesome/css/all.min.css`

Comment: FontAwesome recommend that their npm package is installed as a `devDependency`. For this solution to work (in production) should the package be installed as a regular dependency?

Comment: To answer my own question: yes, it needs to be installed with `--save` and not `--save-dev`

Answer (score 5):

Since I'm currently learning node js, I also encountered this problem. All I did was, first of all, install the font-awesome using npm

```
npm install font-awesome --save-dev
```

after that, I set a static folder for the css and fonts:

```
app.use('/fa', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/font-awesome/css'));
app.use('/fonts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts'));
```

and in html:

```
<link href="/fa/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and it works fine!

Answer (score 4):

You could add it between your `<head></head>` tag like so:

```
<head>
  <link href="./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Or whatever your path to your `node_modules` is.

Edit (2017-06-26) - Disclaimer: THERE ARE BETTER ANSWERS. PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS METHOD. At the time of this original answer, good tools weren't as prevalent. With current build tools such as webpack or browserify, it probably doesn't make sense to use this answer. I can delete it, but I think it's important to highlight the various options one has and the possible dos and do nots.

Comment: I don't think anybody would want to include the node_modules directory in a build and reference it directly.

Comment: I understand, but it's still an option. There isn't a single answer for a solution. :) If you have a bundling system, then you can `@import '../node_modules/...'` like other answers have indicated.

Comment: in comparison to other answers, i feel this is best. you are still referencing the relative path via node_modules in the other answers. if the location of the css file within `font-awesome` were to change, this would need tweaking or maintenance as much as the other answers. difference is this answer needs no transpilation or tasks. it just places the import exactly where it should be expected; in a `<link>` tag.

Comment: A simple npm forder will have at its minimum 10+MB, no user will want to add that weight to a project for any reason. The whole point of npm is to help while in Development and minify/reduce Production size once build.

Don't think this is a good option even when it works. ; )

Comment: I added the following disclaimer:

At the time of this original answer, good tools weren't as prevalent. With current build tools such as webpack or browserify, it probably doesn't make sense to use this answer. I can delete it, but I think it's important to highlight the various options one has and the possible dos and do nots.

Answer (score 3):

I came upon this question having a similar problem and thought I would share another solution:

If you are creating a Javascript application, font awesome icons can also be referenced directly through Javascript:

First, do the steps in [this guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/getting-started):

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
```

Then inside your javascript:

```
import { library, icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faStroopwafel } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faStroopwafel)

const fontIcon= icon({ prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'stroopwafel' })
```

After the above steps, you can insert the icon inside an HTML node with:

```
htmlNode.appendChild(fontIcon.node[0]);
```

You can also access the HTML string representing the icon with:

```
fontIcon.html
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using npm you could use Gulp.js a build tool to build your Font Awesome packages from SCSS or LESS. This example will compile the code from SCSS.

1. Install [Gulp.js](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start)  v4 locally and CLI V2 globally.
2. Install a plugin called [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) using npm.
3. Create a main.scss file in your public folder and use this code:

   ```
   $fa-font-path: "../webfonts";
   @import "fontawesome/fontawesome";
   @import "fontawesome/brands";
   @import "fontawesome/regular";
   @import "fontawesome/solid";
   @import "fontawesome/v4-shims";
   ```
4. Create a gulpfile.js in your app directory and copy this.

   ```
   const { src, dest, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
   const sass = require('gulp-sass');
   const fs = require('fs');

   function copyFontAwesomeSCSS() {
      return src('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(dest('public/scss/fontawesome'));
   }

   function copyFontAwesomeFonts() {
      return src('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/*')
        .pipe(dest('public/dist/webfonts'));
    }

    function compileSCSS() { 
      return src('./public/scss/theme.scss')
        .pipe(sass()).pipe(dest('public/css'));
    }

    // Series completes tasks sequentially and parallel completes them asynchronously
    exports.build = parallel(
      copyFontAwesomeFonts,
      series(copyFontAwesomeSCSS, compileSCSS)
    );
   ```
5. Run 'gulp build' in your command line and watch the magic.

Answer (score 0):

**SASS modules version**

Soon, using `@import` in sass will be depreciated. SASS modules [configuration](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#configuration) works using `@use` instead.

```
@use "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome"  with (
  $fa-font-path: "../icons"
);

.icon-user {
  @extend .fa;
  @extend .fa-user;
}
```