# How can I add a location icon in the react bootsrap FormControl text field component?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-bootstrap, font-awesome-5

1. LocationSearchComponent.js
   [when I add &#xf3c5 Unicode showing empty icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjYtW.png)

```
const LocationSearchComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Form className="locationForm">
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Control
          className="locationSearchTextField"
          type="text"
          placeholder="&#xf3c5; Enter your location"
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Comment: What is your fontawesome version?

Comment: these are the packages i am using along with version ``` "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.12" ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add font-awesome to your `index.html` using CDN like this:

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
```

And add this css to your component:

```
.locationSearchTextField::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: Circular, "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.locationSearchTextField::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: Circular, "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.locationSearchTextField:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: Circular, "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-alex-4jpcw6?file=/src/LocationSearchComponent.css) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: Thank you it worked, one question I have, can we add the hosted URL directly in the index.html, and for that do we need to take any license? I am completely new to the Icon functionality in React

Comment: The css that we've linked has [free licence](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css), [also see](https://fontawesome.com/license/free). So we can use it anywhere in our app. One more thing, can you please accept my answer by clicking the check icon on the left side of my answer?

Comment: okay Thank you, one last question is there any other way, like adding a package in the package.json and importing the min.css file from the awesome fonts

Comment: I could not make it work. But the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406538/how-to-use-font-awesome-icons-from-node-modules) show there are some alternatives. I think it would be easier using sass or less.